# Ajax display msg on submit without refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am submitting form data via Ajax and would like to display a message above the form on successful submit.

Currently the form does send the data successfully. It should render the feedback message on form submit `<?php $this->renderFeedbackMessages(); ?>` as defined in my config.php

Where am I going wrong? Possibly doing things in the wrong order due to first time working with mvc?

my **config.php** file I have the following defined;

```
define("FEEDBACK_BOOK_ADD_SUCCESSFUL", "Book add successful.");
```

my **model**;

```
public function addIsbn($isbn)
{
    // insert query here  
    $count =  $query->rowCount();
        if ($count == 1) {
            $_SESSION["feedback_positive"][] = FEEDBACK_BOOK_ADD_SUCCESSFUL;
    return true;
        } else {
            $_SESSION["feedback_negative"][] = FEEDBACK_NOTE_CREATION_FAILED;
    }
    // default return
    return false;
}
```

my **controller**;

```
function addIsbn()  
{
    // $_POST info here
    header('location: ' . URL . 'admin/searchIsbn');
}
```

my **searchIsbn.php**;

```
<?php $this->renderFeedbackMessages(); ?>

<div>
//my html form here
</div>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
$('#form').submit(function() {

       event.preventDefault();

       var isbn = $('#isbn_search').val();

       var url='https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:'+isbn;

        $.getJSON(url,function(data){

            $.each(data.items, function(entryIndex, entry){  

                $('#result').html('');

                var html = '<div class="result">';  

                html += '<h3>' + entry.volumeInfo.isbn + '</h3>';
                html += '<hr><button type="button" id="add" name="add">add to library</button></div>';  

                $(html).hide().appendTo('#result').fadeIn(1000);

                $('#add').click(function(ev) {
                    $.ajax({
                         type: 'POST',
                         url: '<?php echo URL; ?>admin/addIsbn',
                         data: {
                             'isbn' : isbn   
                         }      
                    });
                });
            });
        });
 });
</script>
```

No console error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page is making the call to `admin/addIsbn` which is redirected to `admin/searchIsbn`. So you already have the output of `renderFeedbackMessages()` being sent to your function.

Use the `success` callback to output the results to the page:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '<?php echo URL; ?>admin/addIsbn',
  data: {
    'isbn' : isbn   
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are redirecting here:

```
header('location: ' . URL . 'admin/addIsbn');
```

remove it.

echo the success message here and add it to an HTML element's `.html()` API.

Your page will not be refreshed.

Comment: Thanks @Programming Student I have since updated my question. I have changed to redirect now to admin/searchIsbn, it should re-direct to the same page however output my renderFeedbackMessages() - which it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work was to add an auto-refresh to my Ajax success function as follows;

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Working however open to suggestions.

Comment: Why not just use the success function to get the contents of the page and insert it into the desired element? You're pointing it at `admin/searchIsbn`, so you have the output of `renderFeedbackMessages()` available to your callback.

Comment: @Jeremiah Winsley If you convert to answer i'll accept :)